# Can dimensional regularization solve the fine-tuning problem?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, regularization, fine-tuning, dimensional-regularization

I have recently read that the dimensional regularization scheme is "special" because power law divergences are absent. It was argued that power law divergences were unphysical and that there was no fine-tuning problem. I was immediately suspicious.

Let us take $\lambda\phi^4$ theory. For the renormalized mass $m$ (not a physical mass) with dimensional regularization,
$$
m^2_\text{phys} = m^2(\mu) + m^2_\text{phys}\frac{\lambda}{16\pi^2}\ln({\mu^2}/{m^2_\text{phys}}) 
$$
This looks promising, but $m$ is a renormalized mass, not a true parameter of a Lagrangian that will be set by some new physics, like string theory or whatever it is.

For the Lagrangian mass with a cut-off regulator,
$$
m^2_\text{phys} = m_0^2(\Lambda) + \frac{\lambda}{16\pi^2} \Lambda^2
$$
which is basically what I understand to be the fine-tuning problem. We would need incredible cancellations for $m_0\ll \Lambda$ at the low scale. Here I understand $m_0$ to be a "real" parameter determining the theory, whereas $m$ in dimensional regularisation was just an intermediate parameter that scheme.

I suspect that these two equations are related by the wave-function renormalization, 
$$
m_0^2=Z m^2 = (1+\text{const}\Lambda^2/m^2 + \ldots) m^2
$$ 
If I am correct, not much has improved with dimensional regularization. We've sort of hidden the fine-tuning in the wave-function renormalization.

You don't see the fine-tuning in dimensional regularization because you are working with a renormalized mass. The bare Lagrangian mass $m_0$ is the one being set at the high-scale by some physics we don't know about. So it's $m_0$ that we need to worry about being fine-tuned. With dimensional regularization, we see that $m$ isn't fine-tuned, but that isn't a big deal.

Have I misunderstood something? I feel like I am missing something. Can dimensional regularization solve the fine-tuning problem? Is dimensional regularization really special?

EDIT

I am not necessarily associating $\Lambda$ with a massive particle, just a massive scale at which $m_0$ is set to a finite value.

It seems to me that the dimensional regularisation cannot help me understand how $m_0$ runs, or the tuning associated with setting it at the high scale, especially as it obliterates information about the divergences. I have no idea how quickly to take the $\epsilon\to0$ limit.

I can do something like,

$$
m_0^2 = Z m^2 = ( 1 +\lambda/\epsilon) m^2\\
m_0^2(\epsilon_1) - m_0^2(\epsilon_2) = m^2 \lambda (1/\epsilon_1 - 1/\epsilon_2)
$$
Now if I take $\epsilon_1$ somehow so that it corresponds to a low scale, and  $\epsilon_2$ somehow corresponds to a high scale. $m_0^2(\epsilon_1) $ needs to be small for a light scalar. But then I need to fine tune the massive number on the right hand side with the bare mass at a high scale. The fine tuning is still there. Admittedly this is very informal because I have no idea how to really interpret $\epsilon$

Comment: Honestly if you find a way to interpret $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ divergences physically purely based on dim reg let me know. Any arguments I have seen are ultimately grounded in the intuition one gets from more 'physical' regulators like a hard cutoff or Pauli- Villars.

Comment: Every regulator carries an opinion about the UV physics. Intuitively, I think dimensional regularization assumes that _there is no new UV physics_. Further, one consistent way to compute divergent integrals is to just drop the power-law divergences, which is what dim-reg does. So it is unphysical inasmuch as you expect to see new UV physics.

Comment: Where have you read this from? A paper?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Dimensional regularization (i.e., dim-reg) is a method to regulate divergent integrals. Instead of working in $4$ dimensions where loop integrals are divergent you can work in $4-\epsilon$ dimensions. This trick enables you to pick out the divergent part of the integral, as using a cutoff does. However, it treats all divergences equally so you can't differentiate between a quadratic and logarithmic divergence using dim-reg. All it really does is hide the fine-tuning, not fix the problem.

As an example lets do the mass renormalization of $\phi^4$ theory. The diagram gives,
\begin{equation} 
\int \frac{  - i \lambda }{ 2} \frac{ i }{ \ell ^2 - m ^2 + i \epsilon } \frac{ d ^4 \ell }{ (2\pi)^4 } = \lim _{ \epsilon \rightarrow 0 }\frac{ - i \lambda }{ 2} \frac{ - i }{ 16 \pi ^2 } \left( \frac{ 2 }{ \epsilon } + \log 4 \pi - \log m ^2  - \gamma \right)
 \end{equation} 
where I have used the ``master formula'' in the back of Peskin and Schoeder, pg. A.44 (note that this $ \epsilon $ doesn't have anything to do with the $ \epsilon $ in the propagator). This gives a mass renormalization of
\begin{equation} 
\delta m ^2 = \lim _{ \epsilon \rightarrow 0 } \frac{ \lambda  }{ 32 \pi ^2 } \left( \frac{ 2 }{ \epsilon } + \log 4 \pi - \log m ^2  - \gamma \right)
\end{equation} 
Keeping only the divergent part:
\begin{equation} 
\delta m ^2 = \lim _{ \epsilon \rightarrow 0 } \frac{ \lambda  }{ 16 \pi ^2 }  \frac{ 1 }{ \epsilon } 
\end{equation} 
This is the same result as the one you arrived at above, but uses a different regulator. You regulated your integral using a cut-off, I did using dim-reg. The mass correction diverges as $ \sim \frac{1}{ \epsilon }$. This is where the sensitivity to the UV physics is stored.

A cutoff, which is a dimensionful number, tells you something very physical, the scale of new physics. The $\epsilon$ is unphysical, just a useful parameter.

With a cutoff, depending on how badly your divergence is, you will get different scaling with the cutoff; it will be either logarithmic, quadratic, or quartic (which has real physical significance, namely, how sensitive the result is tothe high energy physics). However, dim-reg regulated integrals always diverge the same way, like $ \frac{1}{ \epsilon } $. Dim-reg doesn't care how your integral diverges. It can be a logarithmically divergent integral but using dim-reg you will still get a $ \frac{1}{ \epsilon }$ dependence. The reason for this is that $ \epsilon $ is not a physical quantity here. Its just a useful trick to regulate the integrals.

Since dim-reg hides the type of divergences that you have, people like to say that dim-reg solves the fine-tuning problem, because by using it you don't get to see how badly your divergence is. This viewpoint is clearly flawed since the quadratic divergences are still there, they just appear to be on the same footing as logarithmic divergences when you use dim-reg.

In short the fine-tuning problem isn't really fixed using dim-reg but if you use it then you can pretend the problem isn't here. This is by no means a solution to the fine-tuning, unless someone develops an intuition for why dim-reg is the ``correct'' way to regulate your integrals, i.e., a physical meaning for $ \epsilon $ (which its safe to say there isn't one).

Comment: Thanks. Where is the fine-tuning hidden in dim. reg.? Can you be explicit? Using dim. reg., what's the easiest way to see that the sensitivity to the UV for scalar fields is still there?

Comment: I updated the answer a bit. The sensitivity to new physics is in the fact that $1/\epsilon$ diverges. The mass correction is infinite and hence the theory is fine-tuned. The point is that using dim-reg this would occur whether you have a log divergence (good) or a quadratic (bad). But the type of divergence is the key differentiator between natural and unnatural theories.

Comment: I really disagree with this answer but I am not going downvote because I find it a bit antagonistic in this situation. I posted my answer below, please feel free to comment and we can discuss.

Comment: @DJBunk: Seems to me like we have similar answers... I'm not sure what you disagree with. The fact that dim-reg hides the fine-tuning? If you use dim-reg at all times, you will never know when you have log divergences and when you have quadratic divergences. So in this sense it hides it. This is what people mean when they say (and people do say it) to use dim-reg and not worry about fine tuning. Though I clearly emphasized I do not at all agree with this viewpoint.

Comment: @DJBunk writes that without super massive particles you won't get FT at all.

Comment: @innisfree, by writing a cutoff what we **mean** is that there are some massive particles in our theory. The cutoff is the new physics at some scale.

Comment: @JeffDror why do you need to specify heavy particles? Isn't the RG running enough? All I need to say is that somehow my parameter $m_0$ is set at a high scale, Lambda. Then the RG running makes a light scalar unnatural.

Comment: @innisfree: I'm not sure what your tuning with RG running? Tuning occurs when 2 parameters have to cancel to a large number of decimal places in order to agree with Nature. This occurs when quadratic divergences emerge because if we take $\Lambda $ to be the Planck scale then $(10 ^{19} \mbox{GeV})^2$ (the quantity that needs to be cancelled with the counterterms) is  huge number.

Comment: Yes yes :) take $\Lambda\sim M_P$, suppose $m_0^2(M_P)$ is set by a fundamental theory. If the scalar is to be light, we need fine tuning. But the physics setting $m_0$ need not have heavy particles associated with it. It is enough that there exists a heavy scale at which $m_0$ is set. The Wilson exact group doesn't need to specify that $\Lambda$ is a massive particle.

Comment: @JeffDror - what I mean is that even dim reg won't hide tuning against a physical scale like that of a massive particle, and that is the fine tuning that matters. That is, start with a model that has some heavy particles coupled to some light scalar fields and integrate out the heavy fermions - then you will see the fine tuning in any regularization procedure, dim reg or otherwise.

Comment: @DJBunk, Yes I agree with you. Since you will still introduce a physical scale in the technique that you mention you will still have fine tuning. However, when people (not me!) say just use dim-reg and forget about fine-tuning I stand by what I said in terms of what they mean - just pretend there is no other scale and use dim-reg, which won't differentiate different types of divergence.

Answer (score 2):

The fine tuning you describe isn't present in the $\phi^4$ model. You need some some other heavy fields around to see it. For example, couple your $\phi$ to a heavy fermion of mass M, Then when you will have a shift in your mass $\delta m^2 \sim M^2 $. There will be other factors of $\pi$ and coupling constants and such, but the problem remains - for large M you will have to tune the bare parameter $m_0$ to get the correct value for $m_{\text{physical} }$. Stated this way, the fine tuning problem appears for a hard cutoff or dim reg.

This relates to to your original question in the following way. When you use a hard cutoff you integrate up to $\Lambda$. But what is $\Lambda$? It is the scale of new physics, which is in this case is the scale of the heavy fermion we integrated out, namely M.

So to finally answer your question - no dim reg absolutely does not solve the fine tuning problem. Moreover, it does not even obscure it, all the same pathologies are still there.

Comment: Not sure I follow. Why do I need to associate $\Lambda$ with a new super massive particle? Why can't I just say, $\Lambda$ is some high scale at which my Lagrangian parameter $m_0^2$ is set by a more fundamental theory? Then i see a hellish fine tuning in the RG running. But where is that in dim reg?

Comment: Btw yes I agree that if there is a massive particle dim reg shows the fine tuning problem just like cut off regularisation

Comment: @innisfree : It is like JeffDror said above - $\Lambda$, the cutoff, is the energy scale at which our model fails and new physics comes in. The energy scale at which our model fails is that one at which there are new particles of mass $\Lambda$ that we were otherwise ignoring.

Comment: Massive particles aren't necessary for the argument, only a massive scale is strictly neccessary. It's plausible that the massive scale is there because it's associated with a new massive particle. But on the other hand, the properties of the new physics could be very special.

Comment: So $\Lambda$ need not correspond to a massive particle. That said, there isn't any other way to "tell" dim reg about some new physics at the scale $\Lambda$, so maybe it is reasonable to put in a particle of mass $\Lambda$ to represent the new physics, regardless of whether there is truly a massive particle

Comment: @innisfree I get what you are saying that $\Lambda$ does not have to correspond to a massive particle and I agree. I would go even further and say the following: Say you have a model with a light scalar field. And say there are no new massive particles that are being ignored and no new physics of scale M that creates perturbative OR non-perturbative corrections to your light scalar. Then I would say your model is absolutely not fine tuned.

Comment: For example: take the toy $\phi^4$ model you describe above - I would say this model is not fine tuned. However, this is only a toy model. A real particle of interest is the Higgs and this is only a $\phi^4$ model in the low energy limit. It is extremely likely there is new physics that talks to the Higgs that will result in a fine tuning of its mass. At the very least there is gravity and would expect new particles of the planck mass.

Comment: That is, assuming one could actually calculate such non-perturbative corrections.

Comment: in the model you describe, it's impossible to say anything about the bare parameters, so i agree. do you agree that a heavy scale at which $m_0^2(\Lambda)$ is set is enough to introduce FT? even if there are NOT massive particles $M\sim\Lambda$?

Comment: ok martin's SUSY primer puts it nicely ... "The argument above applies not just
for heavy particles, but for arbitrary high-scale physical phenomena such as condensates or additional
compactified dimensions."

Comment: @innisfree - one thing that I forgot from my prior comment, there actually is a physical scale to fine tune against in $\phi^4$ theory. There is the Landau pole at $m \ e^{ 16 \pi^2 / (3 g )}$ where m is the mass of the particle and g is the quartic interaction at the measurable energy scale. So here is where my prior argument picks up - we expect new particles or some other new physics at this scale to tune against and so forth....

Comment: @innisfree - so did you mean that Martin's Primer answered your question from 2 lines above? If so where exactly does he say it? If he makes a clearer argument I would like to read it.

Comment: ok! I think we have sort of understand each other now. To be honest, Martin doesn't make it that clear. I find his discussion in the introduction a little contradictory. Baer & Tata, says $\Lambda$ "unknown heavy particles" or may correspond to the breakdown of SM because "new form factors" associated with strong effects. The very last page of Prof. Luty's notes, http://www.physics.umd.edu/courses/Phys851/Luty/notes/renorm.pdf, is closest to my point of view